# Expo App works well on Development but crashes when downloaded from google play

Tags: crash, google-play, expo, app-store

I developed my app using expo and I was able to test it using both simulator and actual devices through the expo app. However, when I uploaded on google play and downloaded it, it crashes right away. It also got rejected by apple saying that it crashed. I don't have any logs to go on and I have been trying to reproduce the error in expo in vain. I tried running `expo start --no-dev` and `expo start --no-dev --minify` but that did not help. Here is my json file

```html
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "App-Name",
    "version": "2.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "Ca-app-pub-xxxxx"
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxxxxx",
      "buildNumber": "2.0.2"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "Ca-app-pub-xxxx"
      },
      "package": "com.xxxxxx",
      "versionCode": 6,
      "permissions":[]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue. Hopefully one of us can figure this out and help the other!

Comment: You might try running `adb logcat` on your computer and then trying to open the app on your device. See https://yoodley.com/view-and-examine-android-logs/ for full instructions. (My error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application <package-name>.MainApplication: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mDefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler in class Lcom/facebook/react/devsupport/b`)

Comment: I fixed my problem by setting `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false` in my `build.gradle` (which is something I had enabled). Another solution probably would've been to figure out which edits I needed to make to my `proguard-rules.pro` files (see https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView/issues/180). No idea if this is your problem though.

Comment: Did you build your app on a native base or using expo. In expo I do not have the build.gradle file

Comment: I looked at the logcat and this what I am getting
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:`

Comment: Ah I suppose I'm on a native base now because I ran `expo eject`. I would look into that error more though.